# Force explicit return statements in Groovy, especially with RxJava based code?

Tags: java, groovy, return, rx-java

I've already burned a number of times by the implicit return statements in Groovy, **especially** with *RxJava*.  Is there a declaration or setting that will put Groovy in a mode where any values returned via an implicit *return* statement will be ignored (not returned)?

In Groovy when using Reactive Extensions forgetting to return an Observable leads to hard to debug "zombie" situations where sequences stop emitting values after seemingly minor changes.

Another difficult debugging situation is created by dropping a statement that would be innocuous in an *explicit-return* language, by accidentally putting at the end of an operator closure or some method that must return an observable, and now unwittingly returns some other type due to the new statement that occludes the needed Observable return value on a previous statement, thereby blowing up the Observable sequence.

This is not a nitpick.  I've already lost a lot of time chasing down problems that would never have happened if only explicit return statements returned values.  I think Groovy is a powerful language and I really don't have time to rewrite the Groovy code base I am working in Java to get what I want.  So I am hoping there's a Groovy setting that will do what I want.

Comment: No there is not.  My rule of thumb: if its a oneliner implicit is ok.  otherwise go with the explicit one. But maybe you suffer from the other way around. It would help to add the code in question.

Comment: RxJava is hard to debug. Groovy is hard to debug. Using both at the same time? Well, I hope you're not writing software for a missile or a heart pump.

Comment: @Malt I inherited this code and I am not being given the time it would take to rewrite it in plain Java.  Not even close.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a declaration or setting that will put Groovy in a mode
>   where any values returned via an implicit return statement will be
>   ignored (not returned)?

No there isn't.  You could write an AST transformation that imposed whatever rules you like and you could have a static analysis tool like codenarc complain for non-void methods that don't have an explicit return, but the answer to your question as asked is "no".

Comment: Thanks.  Regarding the AST transformation approach.  Is that a big job and if you were in my shoes would you consider it worth it, especially given how "bullet proof" that solution would be or would not be for my situation?  If you feel it would be worth it, what are the risks to the rest of the body when it comes to unintended consequences the transformation might have on the rest of the code?

Comment: "Is that a big job and if you were in my shoes would you consider it worth it..." - No, it wouldn't be a big job and no, I wouldn't consider it worth it.  I think a better idea is to understand the language and the runtime and not get hung up on the language's support for implicit returns.